# Ajax success function not outputting text sent by Php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xdebug

I am uploading multiple files with this PHP script below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['uploadfile'])){
    $total_files = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
    if( $total_files > 0){

        for($i=0; $i<$total_files; $i++) {

            $file_name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp  = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'][$i]; 

            $upload_Path = "storage/".$file_name;

            //var_dump($file_size); 
            //die; 

            if($file_size > 8000000){
                echo ('Total upload size must be less than 8 MB.');
                die;
            }   

            if($file_tmp == ""){
                echo ('There is no file path.');    
                die;    
            }
            else{
                if(!file_exists($upload_Path)){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_Path);
                }
                else{
                    $name = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                    $ext  = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $new_name = $name.rand().'.'.$ext;

                    $new_Path = "storage/".$new_name;
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $new_Path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    die('File uploaded successfully!');
}
?>
```

but the problem is that whenever an error occurs such as `echo ('Total upload size must be less than 8 MB.');` it doesn't get outputed using ajax. But when a successful upload is done it shows `File uploaded successfully!`.

My AJAX is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'mupld.php',
                data: formdata,
                processData:false,
                contentType:false,
                success: function(response){
                    alert('Success: '+response);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    alert('Error: '+status+' '+error);
                }
            });
```

On doing a var dump I dont get any output for uploads above 8mb but for below that I get

```
Success: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>3283515</font>
</pre>
```

Comment: And what is the php.ini setting for max file size?

Comment: Php.ini is set to 8mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jeff Bucket was right, so I edited my answer:

Actually, you should handle those errors in your success callback. The error() callback is reserved for situations where the connection between browser and server just breaks, and the error() parameters expect to handle those kind of situations, for example a typical textStatus error should be 'Not Found' or 'Internal Server Error', but no 'Total upload size must be less than 8 MB.'.

You should return an array with information you can use in the client, and handle that in success(), like:

try{

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploadfile'])){
    $total_files = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
    if( $total_files > 0){

        for($i=0; $i<$total_files; $i++) {

            $file_name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp  = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'][$i];

            $upload_Path = "storage/".$file_name;

            //var_dump($file_size);
            //die;

            if($file_size > 8000000){
                echo json_encode( array('status' => 'failure'  , 'msg' => 'Total upload size must be less than 8 MB.')  );
                die();
            }

            if($file_tmp == ""){
                echo json_encode( array('status' => 'failure'  , 'msg' => 'There is no filepath.')  );
                die;
            }
            else{
                if(!file_exists($upload_Path)){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_Path);
                }
                else{
                    $name = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                    $ext  = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $new_name = $name.rand().'.'.$ext;

                    $new_Path = "storage/".$new_name;
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $new_Path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode( array('status' => 'success'  , 'msg' => 'File uploaded succesfully.')  );
    die();
}

else{

    echo json_encode(array("status" => "error" , "msg" => "No file was found when processing uploaded files" ) );
    die();
}


}
catch(Exception $ex){

echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error' , 'msg' => 'An unhandled exception raised: ' . $ex->getMessage() ) );
die();
}
finally{
    die();
}
```

Then in your $.ajax() function:

```
$("#uploadfile").change(function(){ 
//submit the form here 
var files = $("#fileupload")[0]; 
var formdata = new FormData(files); 
$.ajax({ 
    type:'POST', 
    url: 'mupld.php', 
    data: formdata, 
    processData:false, 
    contentType:false, 
    success: function(response){ 

             response = JSON.parse(response);
             alert(response.msg);

        }, 
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){ 
        console.log('Error: '+textStatus+' '+error); 
    } 
});
```

If you specifically want to handle this in the error() callback, you should set the response code of the php script to 500 -or whatever custom code- using header().

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try.

Comment: I believe `die()` still sends an HTTP 200 response, which won't trigger the Ajax `error`

Comment: @Jeff Puckett II, what do you suggest if it doesn't work?

Comment: @Sergeon what to do if I would like to handle error callbacks too along with the present script? A hint in the script would be highly valuable.

Comment: @Sergeon I tried this but it keeps giving me "undefined" in the alert.

Comment: @Ayan It alerts undefined In all cases? Or only when error? It alerts the response object at all? (I mean, try alerting response instead of response.msg ). Also, try to console.log the response instead of alert, and inspect the response preview in the browser console. You could try also to log JSON.stringify(response) to see if something is being given from the server.

Comment: @Ayan "what to do if I would like to handle error callbacks too along with the present script?" Something like "header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");" should fire the error callback. That 'Internal Server Error' will be the textStatus parameter of the error() callback, so you can modify it to send custom error messages to the browser. But is not advised.

Comment: @Sergeon, it gives undefined in all cases. In console also its undefined.

Comment: ok, when I tried with only response, during a success I got the whole array object in the alert, but when there was a error it sent me a blank alert.

Comment: using stringify, during error I get "\r\n" while during a success I get "{\"stauts\":\"success\",\"msg\":\"File was uploaded properly\"}\r\n"

Comment: Ok. I think its being provoked from an error within the else{} block after the `if($file_temp == "")` if block. You should send an error response by default at the start of the script, just change `if($file_temp == "")` for `if(true)` and see if you get the error properly if the cliente (you actually should, but just check).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115102/discussion-between-sergeon-and-ayan).

Comment: @Aylan I moved the discussion to chat. Check it